# Calculate average of columns of column with Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to calculate the average for this column with tcl
please help me

```
frame     Elec
1          50  
2          40
3          30
4          20
```

Comment: Which column? The second one?

Comment: And is that in a file?

Comment: yes it is in a file

Comment: yes the second column "Elec"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a standalone script, (Warning: Self promotion ahead), I wrote a [program called `tawk`](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk/) that's like `awk` except using TCL for scripting, which does most of the work for you:

```sh
$ tawk 'line {$NR > 1} { incr sum $F(2) }
        END { puts [expr {double($sum) / ($NR - 1)}] }' input.txt
35
# Equivalent awk:
$ awk 'NR > 1 { sum += $2 } END { print (sum / (NR - 1)) }' input.txt
35
```

If it's part of a larger program, you have to open the file and read and split lines yourself. Maybe something like

```
# Column number is 1-based
proc avg_column {filename column} {
    set f [open $filename r]
    gets $f ;# Read and discard header line
    set sum 0
    set nlines 0
    while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        set columns [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
        incr sum [lindex $columns $column-1]
        incr nlines
    }
    close $f
    return [expr {double($sum) / $nlines}]
}

puts [avg_column input.txt 2]
```

Comment: thank you very much, the second script it is working very well

Comment: If I want to calculated the average for the third fourth or the fifth column, I only modified the regexp to find it or it is more complicated to that

Comment: @MohamedMastouri See update for one that takes the column as an argument.

Comment: That should be `expr {double($sum) / $nlines}` at the end; means almost invariably need to use a floating point divide.

Comment: thank you very much but I still have a problem with a number like this "0.1" or "-15.6" I'm sorry for this but I'm a beginner in programtion with script

Comment: @MohamedMastouri What problem?

Comment: When I have a columns like this
"Frame         Time          Elec          VdW           Nonbond       Total         
0             0             -216.63       -16.0174      -232.647      -232.647      
1             1             -196.786      -28.6093      -225.395      -225.395      
2             2             -277.05       -23.924       -300.974      -300.974      
3             3             -203.854      -30.2473      -234.101      -234.101"

I have a problem in the average a message error

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but some tips. You need to:

- [`open`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) the file
- read the header with [`gets`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/gets.htm)
- use a [`while`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/while.htm) loop to read lines of the file
- use [`split`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm) or [`regexp`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm) to get the 2nd field
- sum the values (and count the lines) with [`expr`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm), or [`incr`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/incr.htm) if the values are only integers

Answer (score 0):

If your input happens to be (some sort of CSV), or you can steer it into this direction, then you may use tcllib's `csv` package:

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

struct::matrix dm
set f [open mydata.csv]
while {[gets $f l] >= 0} {
    # sanitize input, line-wise
    set l [regsub -all {\s+} $l " "]
    csv::split2matrix dm $l " " auto
}
close $f

set columnData [lrange [dm get column 1] 1 end]; # strip off header
puts [expr {double([tcl::mathop::+ {*}$columnData])/[llength $columnData]}]; # compute avg
```

Some hints:

- [`gets`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm) will read your input file line by line;
- [`csv::split2matrix`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md#9) puts each line into a struct::matrix;
- [`/matrix/ get column /n/`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/struct/matrix.md#22) gives access to one data column (incl. header field);
- `tcl::mathop::+` gives access to the built-in addition operator (outside of the [expr] command) and supports 2+ summands.

Comment: For serious CSV handling, you would adopt [`tclcsv`](https://tclcsv.magicsplat.com/).

Comment: no it is a text file and I change my file with a csv extension but the script dosn't work

Comment: I fail to fully understand your comment. CSV is text, so? How is the csv filename extension related to this? It depends on the content of the file. If it looks like in your OA, then the script works (on my end, at least).